# RabbitMQ connection issues after installing new signed certificate

Tags: ssl, rabbitmq

This has me stumped, hoping someone could help me out. I had a working rabbitmq cluster until the SSL certificate expired.

After installing a new signed certificate, i'm getting the following errors for all connections:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 19-Oct-2016::21:39:27 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.3532.0> (x.x.x.x:43958 -> x.x.x.x:5671)

=ERROR REPORT==== 19-Oct-2016::21:39:33 ===
Error on AMQP connection <0.3536.0>:
{ssl_upgrade_error,{certfile,{badmatch,[]}}}
```

Trying an openssl s_client connection

```
openssl s_client -connect x.x.x.x:5671 -cert ssl.crt -key ssl.key -CAfile intermediate.crt
```

Results in this:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 295 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

But running the SSL key checker with s_server/s_client from https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-ssl.html#troubleshooting works via localhost and port 8443.

No files have been moved, the old certificates were simply replaced with the same name in the same dirs. The CSR was generated with the same key, so the only things that were replaced were the certificate and intermediate certificate taken directly from the SSL issuer.

If I revert back to the old certificates, the {ssl_upgrade_error,{certfile,{badmatch,[]}}} doesnt appear and I can s_client without issues (apart from the ssl is expired error)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was with the certfile itself, went directly to the ssl issuer to download them and move them into the server